# Only scroll inside div

Tags: html, scroll

If I have a div on the middle of the page that is scrollable, how can I disable scrolling outside the div when the cursor is inside the div?

When scrolling to the bottom of the div, I don't want it to start scrolling the rest of the page.

The scrolling in the div is enabled by `overflow:auto` in the CSS

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VtjLA/10/) JSFiddle so far.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this... Even in the jsFiddle, the div extends off the bottom of my screen, so I *need* to scroll the rest of the page just to see the bottom of the div.

Comment: It's for smaller windows, the jsfiddle is just an example. I want it to be similar to Facebooks activity feed (not the main feed) that is on the right part of the page.

Comment: @OskarPersson if js is acceptable ( which i'm afraid is the only way i think ) you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/ZvYvB/      code:`<div id="content" onmouseover="javascript:document.querySelector('body').style.overflow='hidden';" onmouseout="javascript:document.querySelector('body').style.overflow='auto';">`

Comment: @Oskar that little bit of code is sexy. I'm in the same situation and your code was the perfect solution. Cheers mate!